# как отделить php от html?

Tags: php, html

Собственно, как выполнять подобные скрипты в отдельных файлах, чтобы разметка отдельно, php код отдельно?

```
<select class="selectpicker selectpicker_patient form-control" name="patient" title="Выберите пациента" data-live-search="true" data-size="7">
  <?php  
  include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/php/lib/connect.php');

  $query = "SELECT * FROM Patient ORDER BY Lastname ASC";
  if ($result = mysqli_query($link,$query)) {
      while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
          echo '<option value= '.$row['ID_Patient'].'>
               '.$row['Lastname'].' 
               '.$row['Firstname'].' 
               '.$row['Fathername'].'
               </option>';
      }
  }
  ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Отделить, и обращаться к файлу через запрос.

Answer (score 0):

А зачем так сложно делать? Сформируйте ваш выпадающий список посредством `php` в отдельном файле, а потом выводите его в нужном месте в `html`.
Вот пример

файл `select.php`

```
$res = query("SELECT id, name FROM `names`");
if(!$res) exit("Ошибка запроса: ".mysqli_error());
    if(mysqli_num_rows($res)>0){ 
        $select = '<select name="idname"  class="form-control input-sm" id="nameselect">'; 
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){ 
            $select.= "<option value=".$row['id'].">".$row['name']."</option>";
        } 
        $select.="</select>";
    }
```

файл `main.php`

```
<?php  
  include(__DIR__.'/../template/select.php');
  echo $select;
?>
```

Comment: у вас переменная `$select` не во всех случаях определена, в случае когда `mysqli_num_rows($res)` ноль. И вроде как `select` в любом случает должен быть на странице, судя по коду автора.

Comment: Ну концепцию то можно определить. ( а когда ноль, ну да, не скопировал)
Если автор хочет html отдельно а php отдельно, то ему нужны три файла. 1 - код html, 2- код со скриптами, 3 - файл который инклудит два предыдущих.

Answer (score 0):

Как то так:

**mian.php**

```
  <select class="selectpicker selectpicker_patient form-control" name="patient" title="Выберите пациента" data-live-search="true" data-size="7">
  <?php  
      include 'file-with-query.php';
  ?>
</select>
```

**file-with-query.php**

```
<?php  
  include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/php/lib/connect.php');
$option = "";
  $query = "SELECT * FROM Patient ORDER BY Lastname ASC";
    if ($result = mysqli_query($link,$query)) {
      while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
          $option .= '<option value= '.$row['ID_Patient'].'>
               '.$row['Lastname'].' 
               '.$row['Firstname'].' 
               '.$row['Fathername'].'
               </option>';
      }
  }
  echo $option;
  ?>
```